# Bash script for leaving nothing but digits, asterisks and hashes on a file?

Tags: regex, bash

So I am working on a project where I need to read output from a serial port and store it on a file on JSON format. This is already done:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    echo '{"content": "' > /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/lastCommands.json
    cat /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/serialContent.json >> ./lastCommands.json
    echo '"}' >> /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/lastCommands.json
    cat /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/lastCommands.json |tr -d "\n" > /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/serialF.json
    sleep 5
done
```

The problem comes when sometimes (randomly), strange characters start to appear on my output files (serialContent.json and serialF.json). And the JSON parser fails when that occurs.

In that file, I only need to store 0-9 digits, *'s and #'s. Is there a way to achieve that with a regular expression?

This is the kind of content I need to keep in the file:

> *#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*13*198564874*1*##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##*#*1##

Thanks for your answer @William Pursell, I had to modify my script a bit so it won't trim my json syntax (which I forgot to mention), ending up like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/home/pi/bticino/assets/bash
while :
do
    echo '{"content": "' > $dir/lastCommands.json
    < $dir/serialContent.json tr -dc '[:digit:]*#' >> $dir/lastCommands.json
    echo '"}' >> $dir/lastCommands.json
    cat $dir/lastCommands.json |tr -d "\n" > $dir/serialF.json
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: You've already got `tr`, use it.  `tr -dc [:digit:]\*#`

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Post that as an answer or this question won't ever be marked as solved.

Comment: The better answer is to figure out how/why the unacceptable data is occurring, and fix that, but for cleaning up existing data, the suggestion by @WilliamPursell is spot on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand your usage of `tr`, and get rid of the UUOC:
Replace:

```
cat /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/lastCommands.json |tr -d "\n" > /home/pi/bticino/assets/bash/serialF.json
```

with

```
 dir=/home/pi/bticino/assets/bash
 < $dir/lastCommands.json tr -dc '[:digit:]*#' > $dir/serialF.json
```

That is, rather than just deleting newlines, get rid of everything that is not a digit, asterisk, or octothorpe.

Comment: Hello, I am testing your solution and it seems to be working :). But I'd like to know what the '<' at the beginning of the second line do?

Comment: The `<` is a redirection, causing `tr` to read the file for input.  (You more commonly see it written after the command as `cmd < file`.)